# VSTS User Access level using TFS obect model library

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to get user access rights in VSTS using object model library. I want to know either user has "Basic" or "Stackholder" rights.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a GET method in the rest API for VSTS: User Entitlements.

It returns a user's entitlements (crazy right) which includes `accountLicenseType` in `accessLevel`

```
GET https://{accountName}.vsaex.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}?api-version=4.1-preview.1

"accessLevel": {
    "licensingSource": "account",
    **"accountLicenseType": "stakeholder",**
    "msdnLicenseType": "none",
    "licenseDisplayName": "Stakeholder",
    "status": "active",
    "statusMessage": "",
    "assignmentSource": "unknown"
  },
  "lastAccessedDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
  "projectEntitlements": [],
  "extensions": [],
  "groupAssignments": []
}
```

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1

Comment: I am using WebApi for REST in my app. How can I get userentitlements through Web Api?

Answer (score 0):

You could RestClinet to call the API and fetch response json info, you’ll need to also install the **[RestSharp NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp)** package. Simple REST and HTTP API Client

A sample code to get a list of VSTS users for your reference:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    // Asking for a maximum of 1000 users to be returned
    var client = new RestClient("https://YOUR-ACCOUNT-HERE.vsaex.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=4.1-preview&top=1000");
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
    request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic YOUR-PAT-HERE!");
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

    var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(response.Content);

    foreach (var user in users.value.OrderBy(x => x.user.mailAddress))// Sorting results by e-mail address
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{user.user.mailAddress},{user.lastAccessedDate.ToLocalTime():yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss},{user.accessLevel.licenseDisplayName}");
    }

    Console.ReadKey(); // Pause the command window (for testing)
}
```

More details please refer this tutorial blog:  [GET A LIST OF VSTS USERS WITH APIS](https://blog.devmatter.com/get-a-list-of-vsts-users-with-apis/)

The [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/memberentitlementmanagement/user%20entitlements/get?view=vsts-rest-4.1) you should use :

```
GET https://{accountName}.vsaex.visualstudio.com/_apis/userentitlements/{userId}?api-version=4.1-preview.1
```

For a single user, just specific the user ID and fetch the **accountLicenseType** in return json.

Comment: I have an issue with credentials, I use access token to authenticate. I think this information can not be fetched when we are using access token for authentication. I passed PAT but it said "nonAuthentitavieInformation" in status.

Comment: @arsalanyounus Have you tried basic Authorization? Besides, you could also call the Rest API for test with https://www.getpostman.com/ by using PAT. This will narrow down if the issue is related to your code part.